# How to compare local copy with the specific tag in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using tortise svn. I have tag in svn 'firstTag', I have some files changed(deleted/added/modified) in my local site. Now I want to compare the changes between local copy and the tag in svn. How to do this

Answer (score 1):

Extended context menu of TortoiseSVN on the root of WC (Shift+RClick) - topmost menu entry "Diff with URL". Select needed part of repo and compare changed files in TortoiseDiff

Answer (score 0):

There is (at least) one more way to do this, which is often easier:

1. Open the revision graph for your file or folder (`context menu >> Revision Graph`).
2. Select your current revision (the purple dot indicates selected)
3. Control+select your comparison revision (get a second purple dot).
4. Open the context menu on either node and select `Compare revisions`.

If you started with a file, your difference viewer will open with a visual diff on the file; if a folder, you will have a list of files and you can call them up individually in your difference viewer.

This technique is actually more flexible than the "Diff with URL" approach because you can select any two nodes in steps 2 and 3.

[image: context menu in the revision graph]